# Unzip tbz files

Tags: linux, files, archive

I have a huge list of tbz files, approximately 1000 tbz, which I want to UNZIP TO dm4 files. How do I go about it one shot.

Comment: Wherein lies the "conversion" mentioned in the title? Are these `tbz` files simply `bzip2`-compressed `tar` archives? Do they contain the `dm4` files?

Comment: Hello Kusal. Yes, these tbz files contain dm4s. I just wanted to unzip them all in one shot. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `tar`:

```
for archive in *.tbz; do
    tar -x -j -f "$archive"
done
```

This would attempt to extract all the files matching `*.tbz` in the current directory.  It is assumed that each such file is a `bzip2`-compressed `tar` archive.

To see the files while they are extracted, use `tar` with its `-v` option:

```
for archive in *.tbz; do
    tar -x -vj -f "$archive"
done
```

With another implementation of `tar` that does not implement `-j` for handling `bzip2`-compressed data, you would have to decompress the archives separately:

```
for archive in *.tbz; do
    bzcat "$archive" | tar -x -v -f -
done
```

This would obviously work with GNU `tar` as well. `bzcat` could be replaced by `bzip2 -d -c`.

To extract the files to another directory than the current one, use `-C destdir` with `tar`:

```
for archive in *.tbz; do
    tar -x -j -f "$archive" -C destdir
done
```

This assumes that you want to put the files into the directory called `destdir` in the current directory.

Comment: Hello Kusal, I had a question about commands above. How can I store all the extracted untapped files in a different folder instead of trying to untar in the same directory. Can you share a simple example. Thanks

Comment: @mywayz See the updated answer, and also the `tar` manual on your system.

Comment: Kusal, i have situation where all my .tbz files are in a folder which has bunch of other extension files too. How can I make sure I unzip just those tbz files from that folder to another folder.

Comment: @mywayz The code in my answer only tries to extract files with a `.tbz` filename suffix. It will not touch the other files. The last loop shows how to use the `-C` option of `tar` to extract the files to another directory (which needs to exist already). If you feel uncertain about any of this, then back up your files and test the `tar` command in the body of the loop on a _single_ one of the `.tbz` files (replace `$archive` with the name of that file).

Comment: So when I give the command -  tar -x -j -f "/scratch/tbz_file_drc" -C /scratch/unzipped I get the following error                                                                            tar (child): /scratch/tbz_file_drc: Cannot read: Is a directory
tar (child): At beginning of tape, quitting now
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now

bzip2: Compressed file ends unexpectedly;
 perhaps it is corrupted?  *Possible* reason follows.
bzip2: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Comment: nevermind. it is working now. I thought we had to remove the "$archive" and put source path there. but "$Archive"stays as is. Thanks for all the hlep